# Ansible become user error

Tags: ansible

Возникла проблема. При работе с Ansible возникает ошибка вида `This command has to be run under the root user`

само правило плейбука на котором срабатывает ошибка выглядит следующим образом:

```
playbook 
    tasks:
    - name: CentOS Update
      become: true
      dnf:
        name: "*" 
        state: latest
```

В ansible.сfg установлены параметры перехода в sudo-режим (become_ask_pass - закомментирован). Если раскомментировать строку - ничего не меняется:

```
/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

[privilege_escalation]
become=True
become_method=sudo
#become_ask_pass=False
become_user=root
```

Сам playbook запускаю как:

```yaml
ansible-playbook -CkK playbook.yml
```

Почему система ругается на некорректное повышение привилегий? Пароль точно введен правильно. Проверял неоднократно.

Comment: k- запрос основного пароля. K - запрос пароля для повышения привилегий. С - проверка валидности плейбука до исполнения

Comment: У меня вообще ничего такого в ансибл.цфг нету. И в group_vars. Зато у меня настроен пользователь `sysadmin` в группах `adm` и `sudo`. Но это в бубне. Хз какие там группы для суперпользователя в Центе. У тебя пароль у рута стоит?

Comment: Да, пароль установлен

Comment: Ну а переменная `ansible_become_password` определёна?

Comment: да, для каждой машины

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68988510 ну вот тут `become_ask_pass=False` не закаменчено. И есть `become_pass=<password>`.